# Copy value in the neighboring cell R

Tags: r, copy, dataset, cell

I have a big dataset df; its short version looks like this:

```
Time    Block   Accuracy    AccuracyFinal
142     Run2    NA          incorrect
234     Run2    incorrect   NA
121     Run2    NA          NA
143     Run2    NA          incorrect
122     Run2    incorrect   NA
```

I want to copy the value *incorrect* in the neighboring cell on the left in df$Accuracy, so it would look like this:

```
Time    Block   Accuracy    AccuracyFinal
142     Run2    incorrect   incorrect
234     Run2    incorrect   NA
121     Run2    NA          NA
143     Run2    incorrect   incorrect
122     Run2    incorrect   NA
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: `df$Accuracy[df$AccuracyFinal == "incorrect"] <- "incorrect"` ; you may want to read basic documentation on subsetting in R: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1686/basic-subsetting#t=201608311236384809091

Comment: thanks! that worked. I just found another way:
`df[df$Time%in% c("S142"), "Accuracy"] = df[df$Time%in% c("S142"), "AccuracyFinal"]`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this efficiently with `data.table` by specifying the logical condition in 'i' and assigning (`:=` - change in place) the corresponding elements of 'Accuracy' to 'incorrect'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ AccuracyFinal == "incorrect" & is.na(Accuracy), Accuracy := "incorrect"]
df
#   Time Block  Accuracy AccuracyFinal
#1:  142  Run2 incorrect     incorrect
#2:  234  Run2 incorrect            NA
#3:  121  Run2        NA            NA
#4:  143  Run2 incorrect     incorrect
#5:  122  Run2 incorrect            NA
```